# React - how to update the value using useState dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Current UI:
[image]

There are 2 ways of updating the value of `currentPercentage`.

1.Scrolling
2.Click the button to update the percentage

For (1), I use `react-scroll-percentage` library to get the percentage.
For (2), I create 2 buttons to update the value of `currentPercentage`

I want to set the percentage of `currentPercentage` dynamically but I can’t find a way to handle it.

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useScrollPercentage } from "react-scroll-percentage";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [ref, percentage] = useScrollPercentage({
    threshold: 0
  });

  // how to set the value of currentPercentage to percentage, while I can change the percentage by button
  const [currentPercentage, setCurrentPercentage] = useState(0);

  const onBtnClick = (num) => {
    setCurrentPercentage(num);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={ref}>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          onBtnClick(50);
        }}
      >
        Change to 50%
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          onBtnClick(100);
        }}
      >
        Change to 100%
      </button>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
      <h2>{`Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.`}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/still-brook-hqb92?file=/src/App.js:0-2242

Comment: Are you just wanting to update the `currentPercentage` state when scrolling, or do you want the buttons to update the scroll position, and thus the percentage? It's a bit ambiguous what you're asking for, what you want to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(()=>{setCurrentPercentage(percentage)}, [percentage])
```

Updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-fog-iiyem)

Comment: You also need to update the `<h2>{'Percentage scrolled: ${percentage.toPrecision(2) * 100}%.'}</h2>` to use `currentPercentage` instead of `percentage` and will probably want to move the `.toPrecision(2) * 100` into the `useEffect` as well